# Error in replacing value to integer in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace

The dataset named df has a column named TExitStatus and it has the following value_counts:

```
df['TExitStatus'].value_counts()
```

[image: Output]

I need to replace value 'W' to -1 and 'G' to 1

I tried replacing values by the following code

```
df['TExitStatus'] = df['TExitStatus'].replace({'W':-1,'G':1})
```

Still, I am getting values G and W

[image: Output2]

I don't understand how to solve this?, The problem may occur due to the data type of column to be int64

Answer (score 0):

you can use Numpy lib for multiple conditions apply

```
import numpy as np

df2['TExitStatus'] = np.where(df2['TExitStatus'] == 'G',1,
                                      np.where(df2['TExitStatus'] == 'W', -1,df2['TExitStatus'])
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, carefully look the datatype of the column it's an integer. so by replacing 'G' to 1 will not work